# Program to run loop 900K times to select 30 random numbers for each record of 900k customers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, random

I am working on a logic...but taking more time than expected...

Problem:

- Dataset (A) with 60 products ids
- Dataset (B) has around 90K customers

I need to assign 30 random unique product ids for each customer...but repetetions of products cam occur for different customers. Below is my code:

```
#List of 90K customers

web_cust_temp = web_cust['prsn_code'].tolist()
default_nom_ids['key']=1
    

#Allocating num_default ids to each customers
num_default=30    
 
#Create empty dataframe
final_df=pd.DataFrame()
for x in web_cust_temp:
    default_nom_temp=default_nom_ids.sample(n=num_default)
    prsn_df=pd.DataFrame([x])
    prsn_df['key']=1    
    interim=prsn_df.merge(default_nom_temp, how='inner', on=['key'])
    final_df=pd.concat([final_df,interim],axis=0)
```

Comment: Please explain your code. What is `web_cust_temp`? What is `default_nom_keys`?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot  web_cust_temp : list of 90k customers, default_nomination_ids : dataframe contains 60  ids , from which I need to assign 30 to each of the customers in list web_cust_temp

Comment: @RubenHelsloot key is the column that I created in both default_nom_ids and  dataframe inside loop( prsn_df) . Hope it clears the confusion

Comment: With or without repetition?

Comment: @wildplasser for each customer....unique ids to be selected.....

Comment: But two customers may get the same product? BTW: you should put this kind of constraints in the question)

Comment: @wildplasser that's for sure. 90k customers and 60 products...

Comment: @wildplasser yes they can get

Answer (score 1):

One idea here is to use `argsort` on a random array to randomly select exactly 30 indexes for each row:

```
m,n = 60, 90_000

# remove seed for randomization
np.random.seed(42)
seeds = np.random.rand(m,n)

idx = np.argsort(seeds, axis=0)

out = web_cust['prsn_code'].values[idx[:,:30]]
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this and will back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the "initial" code to create both source DataFrames to:

```
nProd = 60
idx = range(nProd)
default_nom_ids = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Product_' + str(i) for i in idx]}, index=idx)
default_nom_ids['key'] = 1
nCust = 1000
idx = range(nCust)
# Customer list, used in your code
web_cust_temp = ['Customer_' + str(i) for i in idx]
# DataFrame version of customer list, used in my code
cust = pd.DataFrame({'Name': web_cust_temp}, index=idx)
num_default = 30
```

To compare execution time, I converted your code into a function:

```
def f1(num_default):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for x in web_cust_temp:
        default_nom_temp = default_nom_ids.sample(n=num_default)
        prsn_df = pd.DataFrame([x])
        prsn_df['key'] = 1    
        interim = prsn_df.merge(default_nom_temp, how='inner', on=['key'])
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df,interim], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return final_df
```

And my code I defined as another function:

```
def f2(num_default):
    tbl = []
    for idxC in cust.index:
        idxP = default_nom_ids.sample(n=num_default, replace=False).index
        tbl.append(np.vstack([np.full(num_default, idxC), idxP]))
    idx = np.hstack(tbl)
    result = pd.DataFrame({'dummy': 1}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(idx, names=['Cust', 'Prod']))
    return result.join(cust, on='Cust').join(default_nom_ids, on='Prod',
        lsuffix='_Cust', rsuffix='_Prod').drop(columns=['dummy', 'key'])
```

Using *%timeit* I compared execution times:

- your code: 19.6 s,
- my code: 1.31 s.

Note that the above result is for *1000* customers. If the number of
customers is greater, the time difference should be yet more apparent.